# Standard ML: How to compute x to the power of i?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am new to Standard ML. I am trying to compute x squared i, where x is a real and i is an non-negative integer. The function should take two parameters, x and i

Here is what I have so far:

```
fun square x i = if (i<0) then 1 else x*i;
```

The error that I am getting is that the case object and rules do not agree

Comment: I'm not clear what `L` is here.

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed it.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to compute x^i or x^{2^i}? I'm a bit confused by your use of squared. It seems you mean the former, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: Your function definition doesn't make sense to me; why would `square 3 4` return `3 * 4`?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to computer x^i. And yes, I am struggling with the logic here. To my understanding x * x would be x^2. So I thought x*i would be x^i

Answer (score 1):

The unary negation operator in SML is not `-` as it is in most languages, but instead `~`. That is likely what is causing the specific error you cite.

<del>That said, there are some other issues with this code. `L` is not bound in the example you post for instance.</del>

I think you may want your function to look more like

```ml
fun square (x : real) 0 = 1
  | square x i = x * (square x (i - 1))
```

You'll want to recurse in order to compute the square.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the part (i-1) do?

Comment: Sure! If you think about how a power is defined, we can do so recursively. For any number `x` we have that `x^0 = 1`. Then for `x^i` we'd want to have `x^(i - 1) * x`. The recursive call to `square` is what calculates that `x^(i - 1)`. For an example, if I had `2^3` I know I can calculate that as `2 * (2 * (2 * (1)))`, where each level of parentheses represents what I'm calculating at a given level of recursion.

Comment: Do you might know of a way to do this using patterns?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean? In the example I gave we're pattern matching on the "second argument" to `square` (really the first argument to the function returned by `square x` for some value `x : real`); either it is 0 and matches the first clause, or the second clause is irrefutably matched (and the value is bound to `i`).

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry, I thought pattern matching is when you use something like x::s (with two colons).

Comment: That is also an instance of pattern matching (given more syntactic context; it could also be application of the data constructor `::`). There you're matching on a data constructor `::` for `list`s. Here, we're pattern matching on a constant value.